# SoapUI Mock integrated in Maven test

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, soapui

I was wondering how to perform some integration tests for a WSClient. My project is built with maven.

In order to test the configuration initialization and some requests I thought it was a good idea to start a SoapUI Mock service. Then I got into that configuration retrieved from some posts.

In my pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>eviware</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>StartupMock</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectFile>src/test/soapui/MyMock-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                        <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                        <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                        <host>http://127.0.0.1:8181</host>
                        <mockService>DataProviderMock</mockService>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

My MockService called MyMock should have been started on http://127.0.0.1:8181/somepath where my WSClient could send the requests. But I wasn't able to start the mock during the `mvn test` phase.

Is that the apropriate way to test WSClients? In that case, where is the problem or the misconfiguration?

EDIT: There is no error. I can't see the mock listening on that port `8181`. The only messages I see (from soapui.log) are:

```
2012-03-21 10:17:21,011 WARN  [SoapUI] Missing folder [D:\proyectos\everest-utils\everest-bridge\trunk\.\ext] for external libraries
2012-03-21 10:17:21,392 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] initialized soapui-settings from [C:\Users\rromero\soapui-settings.xml]
2012-03-21 10:17:23,205 INFO  [WsdlProject] Loaded project from [file:/D:/proyectos/everest-utils/everest-bridge/trunk/src/test/soapui/MyMock-soapui-project.xml]
2012-03-21 10:17:23,891 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running soapUI tests in project [DataProvider]
2012-03-21 10:17:23,894 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running Project [MyMock], runType = SEQUENTIAL
2012-03-21 10:17:23,900 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Project [MyMock] finished with status [FINISHED] in 0ms
```

Than you in advance and kind regards,

Ruben

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/maven-2x.html you need to run the `mock` goal instead of the `test` goal. Please change your `goal` section to call the `mock` goal:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>eviware</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>StartupMock</id>
                <configuration>
                    <projectFile>src/test/soapui/MyMock-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                    <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                    <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                    <host>http://127.0.0.1:8181</host>
                    <mockService>DataProviderMock</mockService>
                    <noBlock>true</noBlock>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>mock</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Two more changes:

- Make sure you start the mock test in a phase previous to running the tests, e.g. in `pre-integration-test` or `process-test-classes`
- Add the `noBlock`option with `true`.

See above for example.

Comment: I changed the goal and yes it started the mock. But it waits for the user to press any key. Is there a way to keep running the mock before the junit tests until the tests are passed? It seems like only can be used after the tests are executed.
Thanks @nwinkler

Comment: Anyway I'm trying to use the `SoapUIMockServiceRunner` in my `@BeforeClass` method, maybe it's a better solution.

Comment: I have added to my example to address some of this.

Comment: what about some sort of `stopMock` goal to run in `post-integration-test` phase, does this exist?

Comment: Above answer worked for me . Thanks. As per today the latest version is `5.4.0` Also your maven command to start the mock should be `mvn com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:mock`. If you want to run tests after starting the mock  `clean compile com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:mock test` will do.